# How to Fix Ambiguous Parameter for Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to copy group membership from one user to another in AD using Powershell. I get the error below. Can't seem to figure it out.

```
Get-ADUser -server "test.server.com" -Identity user11 -Properties memberof |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
Add-ADGroupMember -Member user22
```

The error I receive is

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'Member' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-Members 
-MemberTimeToLive. At line:3 char:19
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Member user22
+                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Comment: I think it has to be `-Members`. What you have is `-Member` as in singular.

Comment: **Add-ADGroupMember**
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [-AuthType <ADAuthType>]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   [-Identity] <ADGroup>
   **[-Members]** <ADPrincipal[]>
   [-Partition <String>]
   [-PassThru]
   [-Server <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]

Answer (score 5):

So lets talk about what the error **Ambiguous** means.

In Powershell you can write short hand

```
Get-ChildItems -path C:\Test
```

is the same as

```
Get-ChildItems -pat C:\Test
```

If we look at the documentation from Microsoft on [Add-AdGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps)

We can see that the command has 2 parameters with Member in it **-MemberTimeToLive** and **-Members**

What the error means is it doesnt know if **-Member** is you calling **-Members** or **-MemberTimeToLive**

This is called **Ambiguous**

The fix would be

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Members user22
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear. PowerShell does partial matching of parameter names, and will accept a partial parameter name if it is sufficient to be uniquely identifiable. In your case, the partial parameter `-Member` does not match uniquely; it could be referring to either `-Members` or `-MemberTimeToLive`. To fix it, you should use `-Members` instead of `-Member`.

Answer (score 1):

it should be 
Add-ADGroupMember -Members user22

Notice the parameter has an S on the end.  PowerShell can't workout whether you mean members or MemberTimeToLive when you just use member.

BUT

you haven't defined which group the user should be added to. Your code needs to be

Add-ADGroupMember -Members user22 -Identity (group id)

You can define the group identity by one of:
A distinguished name
A GUID (objectGUID)
A security identifier (objectSid)
A Security Account Manager account name (sAMAccountName)

Answer (score 0):

Where I experienced the parameter ambiguity to be an issue was when a secondary script that calls an executable is invoked.
Here it becomes a fiddle as the Interpreter cannot identify which parameter is intended and immediately assumes it is the one associated with PowerShell. For instance with a call like:

```
powershell MyPowershellCall.ps1 $ExecutableName "-Usr User `
-XML -O c:\temp\xmlout\my.xml -SQL `"where Entry %like 'Fix-it'`" `
-Err c:\temp\ErrorLog\$ExecutableName.log"
```

In this case the -O and -Err were ambiguous calls being matched to PowerShell parameter variables (i.e. $ErrorAction and $ErrorValue), however the -O was a parameter related to the $ExecutableName file and the -Err the log for the executable.

The solution was to use the ' character defining the literal part of the string and pack the string as follows:

```
powershell MyPowershellCall.ps1 $ExecutableName "-Usr User `
-XML '-O' c:\temp\xmlout\my.xml -SQL `"where Entry %like 'Fix-it'`" `
'-Err' c:\temp\ErrorLog\$ExecutableName.log"
```

Hope this helps some of you guys,

Porky